# React RND drag position x,y not working properly with different screen reoslution

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am working on a project where the user will enter the text something like  below

> my own text here

and the user will drag and drop it anywhere inside the parent div something like website header div. I am using [react rnd](https://github.com/bokuweb/react-rnd) for this.

Example code:

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { Rnd } from "react-rnd";

const style = {
  display: "flex",
  alignItems: "center",
  justifyContent: "center",
  border: "solid 1px #ddd",
  background: "#f0f0f0"
};

const parentDivStyle = {
  width: "auto",
  height: "300px",
  background: "#ddd"
};

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      width: "auto",
      height: "auto",
      x: 10,
      y: 10
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div id="parentDiv" className="parentDivClass" style={parentDivStyle}>
        <Rnd
          style={style}
          bounds=".parentDivClass"
          size={{ width: this.state.width, height: this.state.height }}
          position={{ x: this.state.x, y: this.state.y }}
          onDragStop={(e, d) => {
            this.setState({ x: d.x, y: d.y }, () => console.log(this.state));
          }}
          enableResizing={false}
        >
          User dynamic text
        </Rnd>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

The problem is React RND stores the drop area position in pixels like `transform: translate(18px, 18px);` so If I [test this](https://5jwfe.csb.app/) in different screen resolutions this is not working as expected since it's going out of the view if I use small resolution.

[image]

Above I tested this in smaller screen size and the text is hidden due to static pixel size, Once the user dropped the text in some position like right bottom, that text will be saved once dropped. Any help on this really commendable.

code demo available [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-butterfly-5jwfe?file=/src/index.js:0-1085)

**Expected solution: The dropped text should be responsive even the text is large or smaller.**